# Qual o tamanho da tela para o CSS considerar como desktop?

Tags: css

Quero usar esse código somente quando for ***desktop***. Qual o tamanho para a media query?

```
overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu gosto de seguir o padrão do *Bootstrap*, porque eu acho ele bem definido.
Para desktop você deve usar o **Large** e **Extra Large**

> Extra small <576px
>      Small ≥576px    
> Medium ≥768px   
> Large ≥992px 
>   Extra large ≥1200px

Para definir isso no *CSS*, você deve utilizar o *MediaQueries* do *CSS*

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 400px)  {
    // Code Here
}
```

Vale a leitura mais detalhada sobre Media Queries [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) 
E segue também a documentação do [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa prática. Quando vc for construir o site pense no Mobile Frist. Isso significa que vc deve começar seus Media Queries pelo **`min-width`**

Um dos pensamentos dessa técnica é que quando alguém acessa um site por dispositivo mobile provavelmente a conexão é pior do que quando acessa pelo desktop. Logo as primeira Media Queries a serem carregadas devem ser as menores, e depois o CSS das telas maiores. Portanto sempre comece pelas telas pequenas. Depois as maiores.

No caso da sua pergunta eu faria um Media Queries assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1024px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

*Então só quando a tela for maior que 1024px ele vai chamar o CSS do desktop*

Ai nesse `desktop.css` vc coloca sua classe

```
.classe {
    overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
    overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal
}
```

Nesse link tem várias considerações: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]